# HTC Desire C screen just flashes when I press unlock! Help!

Tags: htc

So I turned my brightness all the way down on my HTC Desire C and it just locked itself. Now when I press the lock button it shows me the lock screen for about a second then locks itself!? HELP!!

Comment: Did you try to shut it down ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I found this after finding the same problem. I too just turned the brightness all the way down. You can get back in by holding the power for a while and restarting... Might do it again and turn the brightness back up and see. Tracker1972

Edit- brightness back on automatic, now working fine again :-) good luck with yours!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reboot your whole phone, just get your battery out once, put it in, restart your phone, go immediately to your brightness settings, put it on high, and keep it always high, solved my problem at least.